# Configuring a dockerfile to send novnc and audio

Tags: docker, audio

I have successfuly made possible to set up a novnc with a Dockerfile.
The problem comes that now i need to stream audio from it as well.
I installed Icecast and Darkice for this. However i cannot sucessfuly start the Darkice

Anyone can set me in the right direction as to what i am missing or doing wrong

Dockerfile

```
# Use the consol/debian-xfce-vnc image as the base image
FROM consol/debian-xfce-vnc

# Switch to root user to install packages
USER root

# Install necessary packages and generate the locale
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales pulseaudio icecast2 darkice && \
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

# Set the locale environment variables
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# Add a new user and assign it to the existing icecast group
RUN useradd -m -g icecast icecast

# Change ownership of the log directory to the icecast user
RUN chown -R icecast:icecast /var/log/icecast2

# Copy Icecast configuration file
COPY icecast.xml /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml

# Expose the Icecast port
EXPOSE 8000

# Copy DarkIce configuration file
COPY darkice.cfg /etc/darkice.cfg

# Switch to the new user
USER icecast

CMD ["sh", "-c", "icecast2 -c /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml & darkice -c /etc/darkice.cfg & tail -f /dev/null"]
```

The config for darkice

```
[general]
duration=0
bufferSecs=1
reconnect=yes
[input]
device=pulseaudio
sampleRate=44100
bitsPerSample=16
channel=2
[icecast2-0]
bitrateMode=cbr
format=mp3
bitrate=128
server=localhost
port=8000
password=hackme
mountPoint=stream
name=MyStream
description=MyDescription
genre=genre
public=no
```

My error

```
icecast@f82e6580d9c5:~$ darkice
DarkIce 1.3 live audio streamer, http://code.google.com/p/darkice/
Copyright (c) 2000-2007, Tyrell Hungary, http://tyrell.hu/
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Akos Maroy and Rafael Diniz
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under the terms of The GNU General Public License version 3 or
any later version.

Using config file: /etc/darkice.cfg
DarkIce: DarkIceConfig.cpp:137: no current section [0]
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run multiple processes in a single container.  That's not usually a best practice; if one of the background processes fails, you have no way to notice this.  Can you run these in two separate containers?

Comment: But they need to be on the same container to register the audio coming from it , or am i wrong ?

Comment: I think the problem is that the container doesnt have access to the sound card of the host machine.